# Monitor status of items in the array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry I am not able to frame the title better. Let me explain what I am trying to do.

I have a list of job objects. Each job object has a **monitor** function which invokes a command using subprocess.run and updates the status(which is an instance variable defined inside the class) of the object.

Example:

```
def start_monitoring(self):
    self.logger.info('Starting to monitor all the jobs.')

    for job in self.running_jobs_list:
        job.monitor()
```

Job class:

```
class Job(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._status = None

    def monitor(self):
        command = self.render() # returns a command when executed gets a status of the job
        command_results = None

        command_results = subprocess.run(args=[command], shell=True, universal_newlines=True, check=True,
                                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        self._status = command_results.stdout.strip()
```

The status of the job can be one of "DONE" or "PEND" or "EXIT".

I want to keep monitoring the jobs in the **running_jobs_list** every 1 min till all the job objects in the **running_jobs_list** are DONE or EXIT

So if the status is PEND I want to monitor it again after 1 min.

What is the best way to do this? One idea I had was to do something like this:

```
#Pseudo code
While len(self.running_jobs_list) != 0:
  start_monitoring()
  sleep(1 min)

# Inside start_monitoring delete a job from the array if its status is DONE or EXIT
```

Comment: Maybe a timer from https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-signal

Comment: There are many problems with your example code.  For starters, your `monitor` function re-invokes the command.  How do you expect that to work?  You should try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch I need to re-invoke the command every time to get the status. But you are right I don't need to render it each time.